# Store image in string

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have used an image in the form of links online.
I want to use the image from assets.
Is there any way ?

```
 child: _boxes(
              "https://nepaldrives.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/ktmnewservicecenter3.jpg",
              27.7147, 85.3355,"KTM Service Center"),
              Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat,double long,String restaurantName)
```

I have used that image in this way

```
 child: Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: NetworkImage(_image),
                        ),
```

Comment: Use `image: AssetImage('your_asset_image)`

Comment: Do you mean, you want to download the image from link, save it to assets and then show it?

Comment: No i want to display image from assets ..

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comment, you want to use image from assets. So, replace your

```
Image(
  image: NetworkImage(_image),
),
```

with

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage('assets/images/your_image.png'),
),
```

Comment: remember to include assets in your pubspec.yaml too